# How to upgrade nodejs from v0.12.2 on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio, upgrade

I tried to install the latest version of NodeJS (v6.9.1 LTS and v7.1.0 Current) but I can't , ieven when I uninstall the nodeJS and install it again , I stuck with v0.12.2?

As a .net programmer , I need to instal visual studio 2015 , and I see the nodeJS v0.12.2 appears after I installed visual studio 2015.

anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Does your issue is solved or not? The Node.JS is not default included in VS 2015, I tried to install the Node.JS Tool 1.2 for Visual Studio through the standalone installer of Node.JS Tool or go to VS-Tools-Extensions and Updates, it is works, then installed the latest version of Node.JS(LTS or Current version), both of the installations are successfully.  Go to Control Panel—Uninstall a Program, I can see 2 different node items: Node.js Tools 1.2 for Visual Studio 2015(version:1.2.40726.00) and Node.js(version:7.1.0).

Comment: Hi Farzad, does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: Solution: Now I'm using Visual studio 2017 - the problem doesn't occur anymore!

Comment: Hi Farzad, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and you can add a reply with your solution and mark it as answer, that will help other community members to easier search this useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bit silly solution, but that's how it works for me.

Solution: Now I'm using Visual studio 2017 - the problem doesn't occur anymore!

basically I just upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 (clean install actually)

Answer (score 2):

Version v0.12.2 comes as a 32 bit installation with one of the Microsoft tools and it being in the path is picked up preferentially. To upgrade, install the 32 bit version of the nodejs from the official site. The path for this EXE is c:\Program Files(x86)\Nodejs

Once this is updated, you can uninstall the 32 bit version and install 64 bit version if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how VS plays with NVM, but I'd recommend trying NVM: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It lets you install multiple versions of Node.js. This is essential for a developer working on multiple Node projects which run different node versions.

```
nvm install 7.1
nvm use 7.1
node -v
  > version 7.1

nvm install 4.4.9
nvm use 4.4.9
node -v
  > version 4.4.9
```

Comment: creationix' nvm doesn't work in Windows at all, right project is this one: [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). But anyway, OP is fighting against VS's bundled node.js, that's what overrides PATH.

Comment: Good call. `nvm-windows` is what you'd need - however if VS overwrites the PATH then NVM isn't going to work :/

Comment: `nvm` makes it easy to revert it quickly, so it's kind of solution.. But using newer node.js with VS needs [some config](http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/#Telling_VS2015_to_use_the_newversion) changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what you mean by "but I can't" - do you get any errors?

Since this question has too little details to answer I can only suspects what can be wrong. I suspect that you are installing the newer version of Node but the old is still a default. You need to set your PATH to include the path to the new Node earlier than the path to the old Node.

There are hundreds of tutorials online on how to install Node. Follow one of them and just make sure that your PATH is set up correctly.